# How to share a USB modem?

Tags: windows, home-networking, modem

Usually I wouldn't have this problem if it was a dsl modem or cable modem but it's really been difficult for me to share this little modem to other computers.

Right now I have my laptop connected to a hub, both computers are in the same workgroup and I have "share this computer internet to other computers"... etc.

Problem is, I don't know what is currently happening... I'm hoping someone would guide me, I have googled and some people have been successful at sharing the connection but it seems I'm missing something =/

Let me know if you need any details, thanks

Comment: Is the connection working, is it just slow?  What kind of hardware do you have.  We need some more info here, before we can really help.

Answer (score 1):

So:

- computer A is successfully connected to the internet via the modem,
- you can ping A from B
- and you want to connect computer B to the internet, across the network via the hub, and A's internet connection?

Last time I did this, I found I needed to specify computer A's IP address as computer B's default gateway in the network settings.

Otherwise, when you fire up a browser on computer B, and ask for a web site, how does it know to go out to the internet via computer A?

You also need to switch Internet Connection Sharing on, on computer A, and ensure that there are no firewall rules stopping the traffic getting out and then back in again.

Comment: Alright going to give this a try tomorrow and see how it goes. I get the idea, and do can see the other computer too, ICS is turned on already but haven't specified the IP

Answer (score 0):

Since its a usb modem,
You can connect laptop A to the internet with that modem,
turn on ad hoc and allow other computer to connect to your laptop via the ad hoc. Not much configuration is required except that you need to allow sharing of internet connection.